# Mixing JavaScript and Scala in a Play template

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework

I'm not sure how this is done. I could hard code the route I'm trying to use, but I'd like to do this the right way.

I have a dropdown that needs to load a new page on change. Here's basically how I'm trying to do it (I've tried a few variations of this):

```
@getRoute(value: String) = @{
    routes.Accounts.transactions(Long.valueOf(value))
}

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {

        $("select[name='product']").change(function() {

          location.href = @getRoute($(this).val());
        }).focus();

        $('a.view.summary').attr('href', "@routes.Accounts.index()" + "?selectedAccountKey=" + $('select[name=product]').val());
      });
    </script>
```

This produces a `identifier expected but 'val' found` exception. I also tried surrounding it in quotes, but that causes a `[NumberFormatException: For input string: "$(this).val()"]`

So how the heck do I insert a value from JavaScript into a Scala function?

**Edit**

Here's my solution, inspired by the accepted answer. This dropdown is defined in a tag that's made for reuse by different components, and the base URL is different for each component. The way to achieve this was to pass a function that generates a URL based on an account key into the dropdown:

```
@(accountList: List[models.MemberAccount],
  selectedAccountKey: Long,
  urlGenerator: (Long) => Html
)

<select name="product">
  @for(account <- accountList) {
    @if(account.accountKey == selectedAccountKey) {
      <option selected="selected" value="@urlGenerator(account.accountKey)">@account.description (@account.startDate)</option>
    } else {
      <option value="@urlGenerator(account.accountKey)">@account.description (@account.startDate)</option>
    }
  }
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('select[name=product]').change(function() {
        location.href = $(this).val();
    });
});
</script>
```

Then you can define a function like this to pass in:

```
@transactionsUrl(memberAccountKey: Long) = {
  @routes.Accounts.transactions(memberAccountKey)
}

@accountsDropdown(transactionDetails.getMemberAccounts(), transactionDetails.getMemberAccountKey(), transactionsUrl)
```

Comment: You're thinking about this the wrong way. JavaScript gets executed on the client side, while scala gets executed on the server side! The only way to communicate between the two in that direction (JavaScript to Scala) is with a POST or GET.

Comment: Yes, you're right, those Scala statements need to be processed before the page is even rendered. I definitely don't want to make a REST call just to get the value of that route though. I wish there were some way to do this dynamically without making a call or hardcoding the route in JS.

Comment: Can you make it part of the routing? Like `location.href = '/products/'+$(this).val();` Then handle it in the route config/controller. Maybe more about your case specifics would help us find a better solution, what is "$(this).val()" in practice?

Comment: @WesFreeman, yes I can definitely do that but I'm trying to avoid hardcoding the route if possible. I'd rather refer to an action name in case the route should change for any reason. But I think that's what I'm stuck with.

Comment: Is it the same for all items in the list? You could then pass it in from the scala side...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a way of storing all URLs in the page, e.g.

```
<option value="@routes.Accounts.transactions(id)">Display</option>
```

Then onChange, you can:

```
$("select[name='product']").change(function() {
  location.href = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: Excellent idea! I just had a major "why the hell didn't I think of that" moment.

Comment: I see no reason why it wouldn't work, but I'd still like to try it first to make sure there are no gotchas, and I haven't had the chance yet. If I try it and it works, then you'll get your green tick and your 15 points :-)