# Using mustache templates in Playframework 2

Tags: backbone.js, playframework, playframework-2.0

Hi I am trying to use mustache templates in playframework 2. So my index.scala.html looks something like

```
@import com.feth.play.module.pa.views.html._

<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>


<title>Test</title>

<script data-main="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/main.js")" src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/require.js")"></script>


<body>
<header> 
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

I am inserting the header via a backbone view.

```
define(['use!jquery', 'use!underscore', 'use!backbone', 'text!templates/View.HeaderView.html',
    'bootstrap', 'bootstrap-dropdown'],
    function($, _, Backbone,headerViewTemplate) {


    return Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $('header'),

        events: {

        },

        initialize: function(options) {
            console.log('headerview init');
            this.template = headerViewTemplate;
        }
}
```

The View.HeaderView.Html is defined as follows

```
 <div id="auth-status">
                            @currentAuth() { auth =>
                            @if(auth != null) {
                            <div class="btn-group pull-right" id="auth-loggedin" style="display:auto">
                                <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                                    <i class="icon-user" id="auth-displayname"></i> Welcome
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="@com.feth.play.module.pa.controllers.routes.Authenticate.logout" id="auth-logoutlink">Sign Out</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            }
                            @if(auth == null) {
                            @forProviders() { p =>
                            <div class="btn pull-right" id="auth-loggedout">
                                <a href="@p.getUrl()" id="auth-loginlink">
                                    <i class="icon-user"></i> Login With Facebook</a>
                            </div>
                            }


                            }
                            }
</div>
```

So the issue I am having is the scala templates shows up as regular text not scala code. If I place the code in index.scala.html it works.

Help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `View.HeaderView.Html` file is not detected as scala code and is not executed/compiled.

- First of all, place it in the `views` package of your application.
- Secondly use a `.scala.html` extension. Otherwise the compiler will not find it.

Comment: I understand that, but how would headerview (backboneview) access this scala template? I need to include the dependency to the template. How can I do that if I declare it as scala template in the app/view folder. The javascripts are in the public/javascript folders.

Comment: never mind I saw another thread on stackoverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709034/mixing-javascript-and-scala-in-a-play-template) that discussed this.

So basically you cannot access the scala template (server side) with javascript. To solve my problem I created the headerView as scala template and included in my main scala template. After rendering on the client side the appropriate divs were available for manipulation on the client side. 

Thanks

Comment: Indeed, that is what you have to do. Create a scala template and import that your main scala template as a <script>.

Comment: do u mean import the scala template and then instantiate it e.g. @headerview() , it doesn't need to be in a script tag.

Comment: Indeed, messed up with backbone views which are in <script> tags.