# Altering the DOM with the Play! Framework

Tags: javascript, scala, twitter-bootstrap, dom, playframework

Hello again StackOverflow.
I've been tasked with modifying a website that runs on Scala's Play! framework and Twitter Bootstrap. I've hit a roadblock concerning altering the DOM. I need to accomplish the following:

(The page being talked about takes user input and passes the server a `Form`, which if
valid writes the mapped `Data` in the `Form` to a database.)

1. Have the user choose a category from a drop-down. This particular drop-down has nothing to do with the `Form`.
2. Based on their choice, query the database for all objects of a certain type that relate to the chosen category via a foreign key.
3. Alter the DOM (that is, show without reloading the page) to display those objects for the user to select them. Their selections are added to the `Form`.
4. Submit the `Form`, write to the database, etc.

Questions:

- Is this a good way to go about what I'm trying to accomplish?
- If so, is there a way to alter the DOM via Scala/Play HTML templates without reloading the page?
- If that's not possible, what ilk of manually written Javascript is necessary?

Admissions:

- I have very little experience with web development other than Play.
- I have very little experience with Javascript.

Resources I've been looking at:

- [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709034/mixing-javascript-and-scala-in-a-play-template)
- [Play docs on Javascript routing](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting)
- [Scala.js](http://www.scala-js.org/)

Thank you!

Comment: This must be done with Javascript. Play templates render the page, and that's it.

Comment: Further to LimbSoup, you can do ajax calls with JS to populate the list.  The AJAX calls will call routes you can define in Play's route file.  Those routes will complete with json objects instead of a Play Action.

Comment: Thanks Gangstead. Guess I need to learn how to AJAX.

Comment: From the AJAX wiki page: `JavaScript and the XMLHttpRequest object provide a method for exchanging data asynchronously between browser and server to avoid full page reloads.`
Sound like just what I need.

Comment: As far as I know, there _is no_ [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) until you hit the browser. It looks like you want to do stuff based on client-side actions You use Javascript for that. If you _really_ don't want to write Javascript and insist on Scala, theres always [Scala.js](http://www.scala-js.org/).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might come upon this in future, the short answer is Javascript.

Long answer:

To do any AJAX work, you'll need a method like the following in your top-level Controller to set up Javascript routing:

```
def javascriptRoutes = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(
    Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
      SomeOtherController.someMethod  // Returns a JsValue!
    )
  ).as("text/javascript")
}
```

Then in the HTML template (`*.scala.html`) which will contain some AJAXy Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.ApplicationController.javascriptRoutes"></script>
```

And finally in your actual JS file (assuming you're using jQuery):

```
$("someSelector").click(function() {
    // Notice that this matches the method name that exists in Scala!
    // Make sure to pass `someMethod` what it needs.
    var req  = jsRoutes.controllers.SomeOtherController.someMethod(...)

    $.ajax({
        url:  req.url,
        type: req.type,

        success: function(json) {
            // DOM manipulation, etc., here.
        },

        error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
            console.log( "Status: " + status );
            console.dir( xhr );
        }
    });  // ajax                                                                
}); // handler
```